# Lock file on iOS Device programmatically

Tags: ios, security, file, passwords, nsdictionary

I want to lock a file (located in the Documents directory of my Application Bundle) programmatically using a password. Is there an API for that, or do i have to write my own encryption and decription mechanism?

I've allready searched on the internet, but i couldn't find the proper solution for my problem.

To be clearly, i want to store a NSDictionary to a file located in the Documents directory. There i'd simply use NSDictionary's method `writeToFile:atomically:` but there is no possibility to set a password?

Thanks for your help,
Br Nic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in two steps:

1. convert your NSDictionary to NSData by using [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedArchiver/archivedDataWithRootObject:)
2. encrypt/decrypt your NSData like explained in this [S.O. topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579453/nsdata-aes-class-encryption-decryption-in-cocoa)

Comment: Hello, 2nd possibility looks great! I'll try that one, Thanks

Comment: @NicTesla: perfect, but you will need both steps, since en/decrypting works on NSData. Once you have verified that it works, you could accept the answer...