# AES256 use XML file

Tags: iphone, xml, nsdata, aes

hi friend i want save  objNSData in my xml file and later i want read my data from file xml and decrypt    and i want use this code  ,haw i can convert NSMutableData to string and later convert NSString to NSMutableData

```
 NSString *strData = @"Bonjour tout le monde, je voudrais vous présenter la Société Futur";
NSLog(@"before encryption : %@",strData);
NSMutableData *objNSData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];

objNSData = [objNSData EncryptAES:@"samplekey"];
strData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objNSData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",[objNSData description]);
NSMutableData *objDecryptedData = [objNSData DecryptAES:@"samplekey" andForData:objNSData];
NSLog(@"%@",[objDecryptedData description]);
strData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objDecryptedData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"after decryption : %@",strData);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some sample available on internet just google for them. Here is a stackoverflow post see if it works for you.

[NSData-AES Class Encryption/Decryption in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579453/nsdata-aes-class-encryption-decryption-in-cocoa)