# Create password protected file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I want to create a password protected TXT file from my app. I don't mind if it'll be a protected folder with the file in it or some kind of protected archive. My goal is to make a file which can only be viewed by those who know a certain password. How is it done in Cocoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than "password-protect" a text file (easily bypassed if the file system can be read by something that doesn't give a **** about your access control), why not write the text file as encrypted data to disk? Here's [one example Q&A for AES encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579453/nsdata-aes-class-encryption-decryption-in-cocoa) and a link to an NSData category that makes it easy to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that totally suits me