# SDWebImage Encrypted image

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

Is it possible to use SDWebImage to download AES encrypted images? If so, where can I access downloaded data, to manually decrypt them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to download encrypted images using SDWebImage. I just went through their class diagram, there is no function for downloading encrypted image. But, you can do that manually in the following way. You can download data in the form of NSData and then decrypt it. For that, you can look into the following answer

[NSData-AES Class Encryption/Decryption in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579453/nsdata-aes-class-encryption-decryption-in-cocoa)